# Aligning a violin plot with a forest plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra, ggpubr, cowplot

The violin plot (b) doesn't seem to align well with the forest plot (a). While the 5th column seems to align well, all other columns do not.

I've tried the `plot_grid`, `ggarange`, `grid_draw` functions and they don't seem to fix the alignment.

My result:

[image: see the plots here]

My code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

#plots

a <- ggplot(data=dat_1, aes(x=varno, y=-coef, ymin=-LCI, ymax=-UCI))+ 
  geom_errorbar(width=0,size = 2,color="steelblue")+
  geom_point(size=5, color="steelblue")+
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, color="black", linetype="dashed", alpha=.5)+  #add x=0 line
  scale_y_continuous(name = "r")+
  scale_x_continuous()+
  ggtitle("A)")+
  theme_minimal()+ 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank())

b <- ggplot(dat_2, aes(y=score, x=as.factor(group), fill=as.factor(time)))+ 
  geom_violin(position=position_dodge(0.5), trim=T)+
  scale_x_discrete()+
  labs(fill = "time",y="ratings")+
  ggtitle("B)")+
  theme_minimal()+ 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom")

plot_grid(a, b, align = "v", ncol = 1 )
```

My data:

```
#data
coef<-c(7.780000e-01, -2.350000e-01, -2.820000e-01, -3.090000e-01, 7.560000e-01, -0.0210000, -2.000000e-01, -0.1790000000, -2.690000e-01, -0.10300000)
LCI<-c(7.240000e-01, -3.670000e-01, -3.940000e-01, -4.310000e-01, 6.950000e-01, -0.1720000, -3.510000e-01, -0.3050000000, -4.290000e-01, -0.25600000)
UCI<-c( 8.280000e-01, -9.700000e-02, -1.450000e-01, -1.890000e-01, 8.020000e-01,  0.1240000, -6.480000e-02, -0.0369000000, -1.280000e-01,  0.05850000)
varno<-1:10
dat_1<-data.frame(cbind(coef,LCI,UCI,varno))

dat_2<- data.frame(cbind(sample(1:5, 10000, replace=T), rep(seq(1:10),1000)),c(rep(1,5000),rep(2,5000)))
colnames(dat_2)<-c("score","group","time")
```

Answer (score 2):

Change 'varno' to a factor and get rid of `scale_x_continuous()` on plot A and you should be fine, e.g.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
  
#data
coef<-c(7.780000e-01, -2.350000e-01, -2.820000e-01, -3.090000e-01, 7.560000e-01, -0.0210000, -2.000000e-01, -0.1790000000, -2.690000e-01, -0.10300000)
LCI<-c(7.240000e-01, -3.670000e-01, -3.940000e-01, -4.310000e-01, 6.950000e-01, -0.1720000, -3.510000e-01, -0.3050000000, -4.290000e-01, -0.25600000)
UCI<-c( 8.280000e-01, -9.700000e-02, -1.450000e-01, -1.890000e-01, 8.020000e-01,  0.1240000, -6.480000e-02, -0.0369000000, -1.280000e-01,  0.05850000)
varno<-1:10
dat_1<-data.frame(cbind(coef,LCI,UCI,varno))
  
dat_2<- data.frame(cbind(sample(1:5, 10000, replace=T), rep(seq(1:10),1000)),c(rep(1,5000),rep(2,5000)))
colnames(dat_2)<-c("score","group","time")

#plots
  
a<-ggplot(data=dat_1, aes(x=factor(varno), y=-coef, ymin=-LCI, ymax=-UCI))+ 
    geom_errorbar(width=0,size = 2,color="steelblue")+
    geom_point(size=5, color="steelblue")+
    geom_hline(yintercept=0, color="black", linetype="dashed", alpha=.5)+  #add x=0 line
    scale_y_continuous(name = "r")+
    ggtitle("A)")+
    theme_minimal()+ 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
          axis.title.x = element_blank())
  
b<-ggplot(dat_2, aes(y=score, x=factor(group), fill=factor(time)))+ 
    geom_violin(position=position_dodge(0.5), trim=T)+
    scale_x_discrete()+
    labs(fill = "time",y="ratings")+
    ggtitle("B)")+
    theme_minimal()+ 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
          axis.title.x = element_blank(),
          legend.position = "bottom")
  
  
plot_grid(a, b, align = "v", ncol = 1 )
```

[image: example.png]